# Just reinstalled keras-gpu from anaconda and getting deprecation warnings regarding tensorflow using windows 10

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I predominantly use keras-gpu to build my model architecture. I currently have the following versions of keras and tensorflow in my machine, which runs windows 10.
[image: Screenshot_From_Conda]
I had removed all pre existing tensorflow and keras installations (including the env directory and all tarballs and packages) before reinstallation.
I have read that anaconda "ensures" version compatibility before installation. Also installing keras-gpu will install the "right" version of tensorflow with it.
That's what I did. But now I get a ton of deprecation warning messages.
What should I do to ensure version compatibility between keras and tensorflow?
Thanks.
Souvik

Here's an example code and the deprecation warnings:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import keras as k
from keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam, Nadam
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_dir = 'C:\\Users\\shikh\\Mark_Everett_Collaboration\\Data\\Washington-On-Brazos\\Processing_For_ML\\SyntheticDataGeneration\\RegularMesh\\Data_Files\\'
data_file = 'fields_rand_cubes12k.npy'
model_file = 'Weighted_Models_for_ML_12K.npy'
# model_file = 'models_rand_cubes12k.npy'

X_raw = np.load(data_dir + data_file); y_raw = (np.load(data_dir + model_file))
# y_raw = (np.load(data_dir + model_file))*47000.
X_train_raw, X_test_raw, y_train_raw, y_test_raw = train_test_split(X_raw, y_raw, test_size=0.2, random_state = 123)
```

And the deprecation warnings are:

```
C:\Users\shikh\anaconda3\envs\keras_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:516: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
C:\Users\shikh\anaconda3\envs\keras_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:517: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
C:\Users\shikh\anaconda3\envs\keras_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:518: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
C:\Users\shikh\anaconda3\envs\keras_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:519: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
C:\Users\shikh\anaconda3\envs\keras_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:520: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
C:\Users\shikh\anaconda3\envs\keras_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:525: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
C:\Users\shikh\anaconda3\envs\keras_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:541: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
C:\Users\shikh\anaconda3\envs\keras_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:542: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
C:\Users\shikh\anaconda3\envs\keras_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:543: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
C:\Users\shikh\anaconda3\envs\keras_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:544: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
C:\Users\shikh\anaconda3\envs\keras_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:545: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
C:\Users\shikh\anaconda3\envs\keras_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:550: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
Using TensorFlow backend.
```

Comment: Deprecation warnings are not errors nor do point to problems, I am not sure what is the question here.

Comment: Hi Dr Snoopy thank you for your note. The issue is deprecation warnings usually mean if I don't change the way I am writing my code now, sooner or later there will come a time when the code will not work. Sometimes that can happen while demonstrating results in front of an important and uninformed audience. I am trying to understand if there's something I can do to avoid a situation like that. :)

Comment: Yes sure but you did not provide any details of the deprecation warnings, they might come from software that you are not aware, and might not be in your direct code

Comment: Good point Dr Snoopy. Added the code snippet and the accompanying warnings in my original note.

Comment: Those deprecation warnings come from inside TensorFlow, and are due to changes in numpy. You would have to make changes inside TensorFlow, this is not a problem in your own code.

Comment: Thank you @Dr.Snoopy .... so if tensorflow "doesn't change itself" we may have to figure out how to use it without numpy?

Comment: Hi @Dr.Snoopy it seems the issues are manifesting themselves into bigger problems: I have posted here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64422489/what-are-current-version-compatibility-between-keras-gpu-tensorflow-cudatoolki