# What are current version compatibility between keras-gpu, tensorflow, cudatoolkit, and cuDNN in windows 10?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

These are the versions I currently have installed via anaconda in a windows 10 64-bit machine as shown here:
[image: Currently installed versions via anaconda in windows 10]

This is the "simple convolutional neural network training" I am trying to run:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
# gpus= tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
# tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpus[0], True)

import keras as k
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpus[0], True)
from keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam, Nadam
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_dir = 'C:\\Users\\shikh\\Mark_Everett_Collaboration\\Data\\Washington-On-Brazos\\Processing_For_ML\\SyntheticDataGeneration\\RegularMesh\\Data_Files\\'
data_file = 'Weighted_Data_12K.npy'
# model_file = 'Weighted_Models_12K.npy'
model_file = 'models_rand_cubes12k.npy'

X_raw = np.load(data_dir + data_file); # y_raw = (np.load(data_dir + model_file))
y_raw = (np.load(data_dir + model_file))*47000.
X_train_raw, X_test_raw, y_train_raw, y_test_raw = train_test_split(X_raw, y_raw, test_size=0.2, random_state = 123)

# ssf = StandardScaler()
# ssm = StandardScaler()
ssf = MinMaxScaler()
ssm = MinMaxScaler()

X_tr_ss = ssf.fit_transform(X_train_raw)
X_tst_ss = ssf.transform(X_test_raw)

y_tr_ss = ssm.fit_transform(y_train_raw)
y_tst_ss = ssm.transform(y_test_raw)

n_samp_tr = X_tr_ss.shape[0]; n_samp_tst = X_tst_ss.shape[0]

n_col = X_tr_ss.shape[1]; n_out = y_tr_ss.shape[1]

X_tr_cnn = X_tr_ss.reshape(n_samp_tr, n_col, 1); X_tst_cnn = X_tst_ss.reshape(n_samp_tst, n_col, 1)
y_tr_cnn = y_tr_ss.reshape(n_samp_tr, n_out, 1); y_tst_cnn = y_tst_ss.reshape(n_samp_tst, n_out, 1)

com_name = 'cnn'

in_lyr = k.layers.Input(shape=(n_col,1), name = 'inpt_'+com_name)

re_lyr = k.layers.Conv1D(16, 9, padding = 'same', name = 'conv_1_'+com_name)(in_lyr)
re_lyr = k.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(re_lyr)
re_lyr = k.layers.BatchNormalization()(re_lyr)

re_lyr = k.layers.Conv1D(16, 9, padding = 'same', name = 'conv_2_'+com_name)(re_lyr)
re_lyr = k.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(re_lyr)
re_lyr = k.layers.BatchNormalization()(re_lyr)

re_lyr = k.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size = 2, strides = 2, padding = 'same')(re_lyr)
re_lyr = k.layers.Dropout(0.1)(re_lyr)

re_lyr = k.layers.Conv1D(32, 9, padding = 'same', name = 'conv_3_'+com_name)(re_lyr)
re_lyr = k.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(re_lyr)
re_lyr = k.layers.BatchNormalization()(re_lyr)

re_lyr = k.layers.Conv1D(32, 9, padding = 'same', name = 'conv_4_'+com_name)(re_lyr)
re_lyr = k.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(re_lyr)
re_lyr = k.layers.BatchNormalization()(re_lyr)

re_lyr = k.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size = 2, strides = 2, padding = 'same')(re_lyr)
re_lyr = k.layers.Dropout(0.1)(re_lyr)

re_lyr = k.layers.Conv1D(64, 9, padding = 'same', name = 'conv_5_'+com_name)(re_lyr)
re_lyr = k.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(re_lyr)
re_lyr = k.layers.BatchNormalization()(re_lyr)

re_lyr = k.layers.Conv1D(64, 9, padding = 'same', name = 'conv_6_'+com_name)(re_lyr)
re_lyr = k.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(re_lyr)
re_lyr = k.layers.BatchNormalization()(re_lyr)

re_lyr = k.layers.UpSampling1D(size = 2)(re_lyr)
re_lyr = k.layers.Dropout(0.1)(re_lyr)

re_lyr = k.layers.Conv1D(32, 9, padding = 'same', name = 'conv_7_'+com_name)(re_lyr)
re_lyr = k.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(re_lyr)
re_lyr = k.layers.BatchNormalization()(re_lyr)

re_lyr = k.layers.Conv1D(32, 9, padding = 'same', name = 'conv_8_'+com_name)(re_lyr)
re_lyr = k.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(re_lyr)
re_lyr = k.layers.BatchNormalization()(re_lyr)

re_lyr = k.layers.UpSampling1D(size = 2)(re_lyr)
re_lyr = k.layers.Cropping1D(cropping = (1,1))(re_lyr)
re_lyr = k.layers.Dropout(0.1)(re_lyr)

re_lyr = k.layers.Conv1D(16, 9, padding = 'same', name = 'conv_9_'+com_name)(re_lyr)
re_lyr = k.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(re_lyr)
re_lyr = k.layers.BatchNormalization()(re_lyr)

re_lyr = k.layers.Conv1D(16, 9, padding = 'same', name = 'conv_10_'+com_name)(re_lyr)
re_lyr = k.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(re_lyr)
re_lyr = k.layers.BatchNormalization()(re_lyr)

out_lyr = k.layers.Conv1D(1, 1, name = 'out_'+com_name)(re_lyr)
model_cnn = k.models.Model(inputs=[in_lyr], outputs=[out_lyr])

# k.utils.plot_model(model_cnn, show_shapes=True)
# model_cnn.summary()
model_cnn.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

def fit_pred_nd(m_obj, esm, mcps, n_epch, bt_sz, A_train_ss, b_train_ss, A_test_ss, b_test_ss, sm):
    ht = m_obj.fit(A_train_ss, b_train_ss, validation_data = [A_test_ss, b_test_ss], callbacks = [esm, mcps], epochs = n_epch, batch_size = bt_sz, verbose = 1)
    b_tr_pr_ss_nd = m_obj.predict(A_train_ss); b_tst_pr_ss_nd = m_obj.predict(A_test_ss)
    return ht, b_tr_pr_ss_nd, b_tst_pr_ss_nd

def plt_train_results(b_tr_rw, b_tst_rw, b_tr_prd, b_tst_prd, ttl, xl, yl):
    sum_train_pred = np.zeros((len(b_tr_rw), 2)); sum_test_pred = np.zeros((len(b_tst_rw),2)); 
    for train_mdl in np.arange(0, len(b_tr_rw)):
        sum_train_pred[train_mdl,0] = np.mean(np.abs(b_tr_rw[train_mdl,:])) 
        sum_train_pred[train_mdl,1] =  np.mean(np.abs(b_tr_prd[train_mdl,:]))

    for test_mdl in np.arange(0, len(b_tst_rw)):
        sum_test_pred[test_mdl,0] = np.mean(np.abs(b_tst_rw[test_mdl,:])) 
        sum_test_pred[test_mdl,1] =  np.mean(np.abs(b_tst_prd[test_mdl,:]))


    fig, axes = plt.subplots()

    axes.scatter(sum_train_pred[:,0], sum_train_pred[:,1], c = 'b', marker = '+', linestyle = 'None', label = 'Training Models')
    axes.scatter(sum_test_pred[:,0], sum_test_pred[:,1], c = 'r', marker = 'x', linestyle = 'None', label = 'Test Models')
    plt.title(ttl)
    axes.grid()
    axes.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.45, 1))
    axes.set_xlabel(xl)
    axes.set_ylabel(yl)
    plt.show()
    
    return

# weights = model_mlp.get_weights()
n_patience = 5
n_epoch = 300; batch_sz = 1000
mdl_dir = 'C:\\Users\\shikh\\Mark_Everett_Collaboration\\Jupyter_Notebooks\\Saved_Keras_Models\\CNN_Models\\Puzyrev_Inspired\\'
mcp_save = k.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(mdl_dir + 'wts_1.hdf5', save_best_only=True, monitor='val_loss', mode='min')
early_stopping_monitor = k.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=n_patience, restore_best_weights = True)
# sgd_lr = SGD(lr=0.1, momentum=0.5, nesterov = True); adam_lr = Adam(lr=0.001); nadam_lr = Nadam(learning_rate=0.001)
# model_cnn.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
# model_cnn.compile(optimizer='nadam', loss='mse')
# model_cnn.compile(optimizer=nadam_lr, loss='mse')
# hist = model_cnn.fit(X_tr_ss, y_tr_ss, validation_data = [X_tst_ss, y_tst_ss], callbacks = [early_stopping_monitor], epochs = n_epoch, batch_size = 1000, verbose = 1)
hist, y_tr_pr, y_tst_pr = fit_pred_nd(model_cnn, early_stopping_monitor, mcp_save, n_epoch, batch_sz, X_tr_cnn, y_tr_cnn, X_tst_cnn, y_tst_cnn, ssm)
susc_train_pred = ssm.inverse_transform(y_tr_pr[:,:,1]); susc_test_pred = ssm.inverse_transform(y_tst_pr[:,:,1])

ttil = 'Train and Test Predictions'; xlbl = 'True value'; ylbl = 'Predicted value'
plt_train_results(y_train_raw, y_test_raw, susc_train_pred, susc_test_pred, ttil, xlbl, ylbl)
```

The error message is as follows:
(It is the same message even if I uncomment the gpu related commands at the beginning of the script).

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-fee4da188aac> in <module>
    141 # model_cnn.compile(optimizer=nadam_lr, loss='mse')
    142 # hist = model_cnn.fit(X_tr_ss, y_tr_ss, validation_data = [X_tst_ss, y_tst_ss], callbacks = [early_stopping_monitor], epochs = n_epoch, batch_size = 1000, verbose = 1)
--> 143 hist, y_tr_pr, y_tst_pr = fit_pred_nd(model_cnn, early_stopping_monitor, mcp_save, n_epoch, batch_sz, X_tr_cnn, y_tr_cnn, X_tst_cnn, y_tst_cnn, ssm)
    144 susc_train_pred = ssm.inverse_transform(y_tr_pr[:,:,1]); susc_test_pred = ssm.inverse_transform(y_tst_pr[:,:,1])
    145 

<ipython-input-3-fee4da188aac> in fit_pred_nd(m_obj, esm, mcps, n_epch, bt_sz, A_train_ss, b_train_ss, A_test_ss, b_test_ss, sm)
    102 
    103 def fit_pred_nd(m_obj, esm, mcps, n_epch, bt_sz, A_train_ss, b_train_ss, A_test_ss, b_test_ss, sm):
--> 104     ht = m_obj.fit(A_train_ss, b_train_ss, validation_data = [A_test_ss, b_test_ss], callbacks = [esm, mcps], epochs = n_epch, batch_size = bt_sz, verbose = 1)
    105     b_tr_pr_ss_nd = m_obj.predict(A_train_ss); b_tst_pr_ss_nd = m_obj.predict(A_test_ss)
    106     return ht, b_tr_pr_ss_nd, b_tst_pr_ss_nd

~\anaconda3\envs\keras_gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
   1237                                         steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
   1238                                         validation_steps=validation_steps,
-> 1239                                         validation_freq=validation_freq)
   1240 
   1241     def evaluate(self,

~\anaconda3\envs\keras_gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_arrays.py in fit_loop(model, fit_function, fit_inputs, out_labels, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_function, val_inputs, shuffle, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq)
    194                     ins_batch[i] = ins_batch[i].toarray()
    195 
--> 196                 outs = fit_function(ins_batch)
    197                 outs = to_list(outs)
    198                 for l, o in zip(out_labels, outs):

~\anaconda3\envs\keras_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   3290 
   3291     fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals,
-> 3292                                 run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
   3293     self._call_fetch_callbacks(fetched[-len(self._fetches):])
   3294     output_structure = nest.pack_sequence_as(

~\anaconda3\envs\keras_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1456         ret = tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(self._session._session,
   1457                                                self._handle, args,
-> 1458                                                run_metadata_ptr)
   1459         if run_metadata:
   1460           proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

UnknownError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Unknown: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[{{node conv_1_cnn_1/convolution}}]]
     [[Mean_1/_1563]]
  (1) Unknown: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[{{node conv_1_cnn_1/convolution}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

I tried upgrading cuda and cuDNN in anaconda and was told there are are several conflicts anyways. So, any suggestions on how to move forward will be a big help. Many thanks. - Souvik

In response to @Lescurel 's question, the warning messages from tensorflow for the initial run are as follows:

```
C:\Users\shikh\anaconda3\envs\keras_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:516: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
C:\Users\shikh\anaconda3\envs\keras_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:517: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
C:\Users\shikh\anaconda3\envs\keras_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:518: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
C:\Users\shikh\anaconda3\envs\keras_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:519: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
C:\Users\shikh\anaconda3\envs\keras_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:520: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
C:\Users\shikh\anaconda3\envs\keras_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:525: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
C:\Users\shikh\anaconda3\envs\keras_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:541: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
C:\Users\shikh\anaconda3\envs\keras_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:542: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
C:\Users\shikh\anaconda3\envs\keras_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:543: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
C:\Users\shikh\anaconda3\envs\keras_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:544: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
C:\Users\shikh\anaconda3\envs\keras_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:545: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
C:\Users\shikh\anaconda3\envs\keras_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:550: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
Using TensorFlow backend.
```

And also this:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\shikh\anaconda3\envs\keras_gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:4070: The name tf.nn.max_pool is deprecated. Please use tf.nn.max_pool2d instead.
```

Comment: Do you have any relevant warning messages from tensorflow before the traceback?

Comment: Not for this run. When firing up tensorflow for the first time there are warnings.

Comment: no i used conda install -anaconda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a couple of things if you want to upgrade to a new version of `tensorflow-gpu` :

First, in using `tensorflow-gpu` for having compatible versions together you have to try to install the `tensorflow-gpu` using the conda package manager. This will handle the compatibility of cuDnn and cudatoolkit.

Second, since `tensorflow-gpu` version 1.14.0 several things have been changed and you have to check whether if your code syntax is compatible with the new version or not.

## edited :

I rewrote your code in my Google Colab notebook in this [shared_link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1QDUryhNycvSALIY0ixphEKktQYFTnNZA?usp=sharing) using the new version of packages and standard methods.

Everything seems to work properly.

Comment: Thank you @Pouria. But which keras, and python versions should we have with them ? Also, is it "safe" to update my nvidia driver?

Comment: I just did conda upgrade tensorflow. It still installs tensorflow1.14.0 and the same versions of cuda and cuDNN. And the same version of keras. Any other suggestions on re - establishing version compatibility?

Comment: @SouvikMukherjee In the new version of TensorFlow, Keras is now joined into the Tensorflow package and you can import Keras using `from tensorflow import keras`

Comment: @SouvikMukherjee maybe your problem is about your python version. create an environment and use `conda create -n env_name python=3.8` for `tensorflow == 2.3.0` or use `conda create -n env_name python=3.6` for `tensorflow == 2.0.0` and after that use `conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu` for tensorflow installation.

Comment: thank you. But I also have CUDA 11.1.7 Driver, now, thanks to an "auto upgrade". Is there a need to to "downgrade" to CUDA 10.1 before doing either of the above suggestions?

Comment: @SouvikMukherjee, I edited the answer, if it seems right, accept and upvote, thanks.

Comment: thank you for your effort ..... the issue finally was fixed. Had to do with the cuDNN in my laptop being uninstalled and re installed correctly. But your version is technically fine as it works on google colab. So I am accepting and upvoting your answer. Thanks.